# Cant find Spring objects in Eclipse Wizard with Maven IDE installed

Tags: spring, maven

I have installed Maven IDE for eclipse and created a new simple Mavenproject.
Then I adjusted the pom.xml file by adding the spring framework.
After saving the project I can see that eclipse is downloading the related jar files.

Everything ok , what I guess.

Now I would like to create a Spring Bean Configuration File with new and the Wizard. But I can't find any entries regarding Spring.

Any help or hint ?

Comment: And why should it? If you only have eclipse that isn't going to happen, you need STS for that...

Comment: I saw this in a maven youtube-tutorial without installing the STS.

Comment: I just installed STS and I can see them now. I hope STS and Maven do not disturb each other. I guess I did not understand the Maven concept completely. Thanks for helping.

Comment: STS already has maven support so why would you need to install additional plugins?

Comment: I thought, I am the questioner here :-) Of course this sounds all a bit stupid, for someone who knows this already, As you can realize, I do not understand this completely, which module is responsible for what. Thats why I am asking here in the hope someone can clarify. If everything would be clear to us both, I would not ask :-) . Obviously Maven is only responsible for dependencies and downloading libraries. Beside we have to install the specific IDE's seperately. Is that true ?